# Silverlight: Creating a modal control

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a window with some contents. I'd like to click a button and another control (a grid/border) slides up. But i'd like the contents of the window that is under this slided up control to be modal. I cannot click or use keyboard to activate anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a modal window I would use the **[ChildWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.childwindow%28VS.95%29.aspx)** class.  Microsoft **[provides the templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278075%28VS.95%29.aspx)** used for all of their major controls and objects so one can take what they did and change it.  The ChildWindow **[template and styles page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833070%28VS.95%29.aspx)** has a pretty good explanation of the layout so one can figure out what to change.  You should just be able to instantiate a new ChildWindow, set its template to your custom template, and rock out!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me you could do with using the `ChildWindow` control instead, which handles most of this for you.  Make a copy of its template and tweak it up to get your slide-in effect.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a control filling the complete canvas and make it transparent.